# Check if value exists in specific column of 2d list (list of lists)

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list (called all_data) of lists:

`[ [142864, bob, 428, robert], [642899, gretchen, 999, siobhan], [999644, nancy, 899, joseph] ]`

I need to find out if a specific value is in the 3rd column, but make sure it doesn't match any other columns.

Example:

428 = true
999 = true
899 = true
142 = false
289 = false
864 = false

I tried using:

```
if any(value in row for row in all_data):
    print("found {} in column three".format(value))
```

but that will find the value in any column (I think).

I've tried various other methods of subscripting the 'value' in the if statement but it either doesn't work or generates an error. I also tried the index function but I'm not sure I was doing it right.

Comment: `pd.np.in1d(pd.np.array([428,999,899,142,289,864]),pd.DataFrame(your_df)[2])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [ [142864, 'bob', 428, 'robert'], [642899, 'gretchen', 999, 'siobhan'], [999644, 'nancy', 899, 'joseph'] ]
value = 428
for x in a:
    if x[2] == value:
        print(True)
```

using pandas:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=a)
df[df[2]==value]
```

Comment: This is simple and effective. Thank you. I will use this for now unless it ends up being to processor intensive (I need to run through this check ~50,000 times)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want a function that will check to see if a value exists in the 3 column of a 2D list. If it exists *only once*, then return True. Otherwise return False.

```py
def occursOnce(value, all_data):
  # Create an array of the third column items
  third = [t[2] for t in all_data]

  # Check the number of occurrences of the value
  return third.count(value) == 1
```

Comment: The value will exist only once if at all; I'm more concerned with making sure I don't match a substring in one of the other columns. I think the answer from Parijat Bhatt works, but I need to do this check ~50,000 times in a row so I'm concerned about performance

Answer (score 0):

There's a really short solution:

```
nums = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9]]
def in_list(n,lst):
    return any([any([i==n for i in row])for row in lst])

in_list(4,nums)
#returns True
in_list(11,nums)
#returna False
```

**any()** returns True if a list contains a True, otherwise it returns False.
The rest is List Comprehension.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license (2.5/3.0/4.0)](//stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)